# PhpStorm function with array parameter alignment

Tags: phpstorm

I have this:

```
$client->setHeaders(array(
    'Date' => $date,
    'X-Amzn-Authorization' => $authKey,
));
```

PhpStorm wants to autoformat it as this:

```
$client->setHeaders(
    array(
        'Date' => $date,
        'X-Amzn-Authorization' => $authKey,
    ));
```

Which settings do I need to change in the code format options in order to get the former not the latter?

Answer (score 1):

go to Setttings > Editor > Code style > PHP

Select the Wrapping and Braces tab

Under the "Function call arguments" Category uncheck "New Line after '('"